# Running Hadoop on Windows 8

Tags: cygwin, windows-8, hadoop

Running Hadoop framework on Windows is always a pain using Cygwin. Is the process similar for Windows 8 just like Windows 7 as mentioned here or is it different ?

http://alans.se/blog/2010/hadoop-hbase-cygwin-windows-7-x64/#.UIIVAsV35T8

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason why it would be different - windows 8 has the same APIs as windows7 (and certainly not cygwin/posix emulation), with the addition of the windows modern related things. There [do seem to be options](http://vorlsblog.blogspot.sg/2010/05/running-hadoop-on-windows-without.html) for running hadoop without cygwin, though looking around, the most painless option might be to run hadoop on a linux vm.

Comment: i just created an account on Azure and using Ubuntu vm there to run hadoop... could not figure out a painless way to use hadoop on windows

Comment: You could always run a VM locally. I'd think colinux would be perfect for this, but I have no idea if it works on modern windows.

Comment: my current system almost died while using Windows 8 RTM ..sadly i cant add misery to my laptop's computing powers